# Django Access a url via multiple namespace

Tags: python, html, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I want to use a multi-level url (appname,namespace, namespace, name)

I have a application called **portfolio_menu**  that has **store.urls** and inside **store.urls** has
**pruduct.urls** that inside has the  view with name **list** page, how do I access it trough the **{%url%}** tag? I will put below the code:

portfolio_menu.urls:

```
app_name = 'portfolio'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('test', include('store.urls', namespace='store')),
        path('', views.menu),
    ]
```

store.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('product.urls', namespace='product')),
]
```

product.urls:

```
app_name = 'product'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'),
]
```

the funcion I want to get, but don't know the sintax:

```
<a href="{%url portfolio:store:product:list%}"></a> #I wish something like that
```

Error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'portfolio_manager.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse traversing namespace from parent to child.

In templates

```
{% url store:product:list %}
```

In views

```
reverse('store:product:list')
```

Comment: in my product.views? Im utilizing class based views do I just paste that code there?

Comment: also i got an error when i  put the reverse  on my program can you check it?